# Fondo de pagina web, problema con <span>

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, web, fondo

Eyy hola, mi pregunta es que estoy realizando mi primera pagina web y estoy realizando un fondo basado en este tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StjmEh211Oc), lo estuve modificando para que quedara de esta manera:[image: Los puntos brillantes son varios y lo que quiero hacer es que se vean igual, el bloque de luces de la izquierda esta pegado a la pantalla y el otro no, intente cambiar su posición para que quedara pegado de lado derecho en CSS pero no lo logre, alguien me puede ayudar?]

Los puntos brillantes son varios  y lo que quiero hacer es que se vean igual, el bloque de luces de la izquierda esta pegado a la pantalla y el otro no, intente cambiar su posición para que quedara pegado de lado derecho en CSS pero no lo logre, alguien me puede ayudar?

Este es mi codigo:

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height:0px ;
    background: #001300;
}


 section
 {
    
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 0vh;
    
 }

 
 span
 {
    
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    animation: changeColor 10s linear infinite;
    
    
 }

 #Luces2
 {
    padding-left:  81pc;
   
    
 }

 @keyframes changeColor
    {
        0%
        {
            filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%
        {
            filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

 span::before
 {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #00ff0a;
 transform: scale(0.1);
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ff0a,
 0 0 40px   #00ff0a,
 0 0 60px   #00ff0a,
 0 0 80px   #00ff0a,
 0 0 20px   #00ff0a;
 border-radius: 50%;
 pointer-events: none;
 transition: 2s;
 }
 
span:hover::before
{
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  

      <section id="Luces">

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

  

  
    
      </section>

      <section id="Luces2">

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <p>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span> 
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </p>
        </div>

  

  
    
      </section>

      

    
      
    
</body>

</html>
```

introducir el código aquí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es reemplazar en el archivo CSS esto:

```
#Luces2 {
  padding-left: 81pc;
}
```

Por esto:

```
#Luces2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;   
 }
```

En la siguiente parte del CSS puedes eliminar el flex-wrap: wrap; en principio no es necesario, también podrías eliminar el height: 0vh, por último agregar al body directamente un dislplay: flex, en resumen, reemplazarías esto:

```
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 0vh;
}
```

Por esto:

```
body {
    display: flex;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

Hay un juego que podría ayudarte mucho a entender como funciona Flexbox, te paso link por si te interesa. Va desde básico a propuestas bastante complejas.
https://flexboxfroggy.com/#es

Eso debería ser suficiente. Quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Eyyy hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta funcionó a la perfección, y gracias voy a probar el juego para practicar!